# Rails 3: Child model directly reference field in parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested model set grouped like this, where c is the join of b and x

b belongs to a / a has many b's
c belongs to b / b has many c's
c belongs to x / x has many c's

In a form, I want to display c.x_name (where x_name is in the x table) in the following nested loop which goes down a > b > c side of the hierarchy

```
for b in a.b's 
   for c in b.c's
       c.x_name
```

I've tried having my show command as c.show_x_name(c.id) and then putting the following in the c model

```
def show_x_name(x_id)
   X.where(:id => x_id)
end
```

However I get a Unknown key(s): id error from the view. Changing the ruby on the view to c.id renders the correct number.

This is my first attempt at Rails 3... what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Give your models reasonable names, a,b,c,x etc is hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got lost in all these a, b, c and x-es. But take a look at [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

add `belongs_to :x` in your c-model, and a `has_many :cs` in your x-model.
Then you should be able to use `c.x.name`

But the `c.x` might return nil if c has no relations to x.

By the way, it's better to either give us the correct names, or some names that might fit in the same way as your original.

And do you have an `id` attribute in your x-database?

Terw